# I'm trying to code a function that finds prime numbers. Some of the "for" loops that I included in the code don't seem to be working

Tags: python, primes

I have been learning how to code with Python for more or less two or three weeks and I came across an exercise that required me to find the number of primes numbers that exist up to a given number. If anyone could help that would be great.

My code seems to be working for the first few prime numbers (it excludes from the list created 4 and 6) but then it stops.

I am new to coding, so this could be wrong, but I think that for some reason one, or even both, of the "for" loops stopped working.

This is my code:

```
def count_primes(num):
    primes = [2, 3]
    for i in range(4,num+1):
        cond = True
        for x in range(0,len(primes)-1):
            if i%primes[x] == 0:
                cond = False
            elif i%primes[x] > 0:
                    cond = True
        if cond == True:
            primes.append(i)
            pass
    
    print(primes)
    return len(primes)

count_primes(100)
```

Comment: I suggest you start by writing a separate `is_prime()` function. You can call that inside the loop that counts primes.

Comment: What is the 'cond' variable supposed to represent?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: The problem is that you don't stop the loop when you find a factor of `i`. So `cond` always contains the the value of the last `i % primes[x]` check.

Comment: You are setting `cond` every time through the loop.  When you exit, it will ONLY have a result from the very last iteration.   Your loop should be `if i % primes[i] == 0:` / `cond = False` / `break` with no else at all.

Comment: @kcsquared I just thought I would include it so that it would check whether a number was prime or not and, afterwards, I could use it to influence the "primes" list. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: for a more efficient way to count primes, check out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). [Here](https://github.com/kwsp/sieve/blob/main/py3/sieve.py)'s an example implementation in Python 3.

Comment: @Barmar ok, will do. Thanks

Comment: @TimRoberts First of all thank you so much, this solved the problem with my code. Could you please explain in a bit more detail why the "break" is needed there?

Comment: @TimRoberts is it because, using the break, will mean that it will break out of the second for loop and continue with the first one?

Comment: Think about the condition you're checking.  As soon as you have found a factor, you immediately know this number is not prime.  You should stop looking (hence, break the loop).  But to know it IS a prime, you have to check EVERY possible factor.